# Problem with title languages from thesis template

Tags: templates, babel, languages

I'm using LaTeX in order to write my thesis and to make a good impression to the reader. As long as I'm not a very experienced user I use a template from [Master/Doctoral Thesis](http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/theses/1/thesis_1.zip) from LaTeX Templates. So, here is the problem I'm dealing with.
It may sound very stupid for most of you but I can't change the title languages at all. Let me explain, I'm Catalan and I would like to write the thesis in Catalan but the template is in English so I'm using `\usepackage[catalan]{babel}` at the beginning. Some of them have already changed but not all and I don't know how to do it. For example: when I write `\tableofcontents` the title is Índex which is correct in Catalan and the same happens with `\listoffigures`, etc. But when you look at the table of contents it doesn't appear in Catalan. Instead

> Llista de figures

appears as

> List of Figures

and so on. I would like to put all in Catalan the acknowledgements, declaration of authorship, etc.
Do you have any advice for me? I would be very grateful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.   Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Have you tried running the file a couple of times?

Comment: Unfortunately the class has hardcoded English names. Since it seems this class is not required, use another one, like the standard ones, koma o memoir.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the stuff that is defined by variables in other classes, is hard coded in the used class `Thesis.cls`. It was intentionally designed to be used within a very localized area of one university.

As it is needed to change the `cls` file to get personal information on the titlepage, you can also rename the hard coded names. Please make sure, to add a comment  line with your name (can be an avatar name) and the date, to keep the file unique.

> Advice: You can have much more flexibility with `memoir` or a `KOMA` class, when it comes to theses writing. You are not bound to any hard-coded stuff implemented by someone with very specific needs. You need to do some reading of your own, though.

An updated version of the template doesn't have this issue anymore. THe advice above is still valid, though.